# Pulling GUIDs out of a JSON string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, guid

I need to pull some GUIDs out of a json string in SQL Server. An example of what the string might look like is as follows:

```
{"priorityArea":"a273b556-f0ab-4d7a-97ac-ddb7dab06130","priority":"Ensure best possible provision for pupils with specific behaviour issues","startDatePicker":"10/05/2019","deadlineDatePicker":"18/09/2019","userPicker":"48698,48693","actionWidget-1555338252504":"85e3ad8f-2586-4612-a9e7-e1c9d3f66181,6b66328f-c13f-4d8c-81ec-fccb8c1caa6e","resourceWidget-1557502650616":"98714348-cf7d-4583-89d5-c7d61cafea72","sdpGrade-1555338253145":"4"}
```

The GUID(s) I need is the one that comes after 'resourceWidget-[number]'. I would struggle with this even if the json string looked the same everytime, but there are further challenges:

1. The position of resourceWidget changes in the string depending on front-end behaviour
2. The unique number that comes after 'resourceWidget-' changes in every string
3. Sometimes more than one resource GUID is returned in the string, e.g.

resourceWidget-1555338252504":"98714348-cf7d-4583-89d5-c7d61cafea72, 87ea276b-5b7f-4b44-b05e-775e9fd2690c

If anyone is able to help, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple `OPENJSON` call and a `WHERE` would work:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{
    "priorityArea": "a273b556-f0ab-4d7a-97ac-ddb7dab06130",
    "priority": "Ensure best possible provision for pupils with specific behaviour issues",
    "startDatePicker": "10/05/2019",
    "deadlineDatePicker": "18/09/2019",
    "userPicker": "48698,48693",
    "actionWidget-1555338252504": "85e3ad8f-2586-4612-a9e7-e1c9d3f66181,6b66328f-c13f-4d8c-81ec-fccb8c1caa6e",
    "resourceWidget-1557502650616": "98714348-cf7d-4583-89d5-c7d61cafea72",
    "sdpGrade-1555338253145": "4"
}';

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,[value]) AS resourceWidget
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
WHERE [key] LIKE N'resourceWidget-%';
```

If the JSON can contain a delimited string, add a `STRING_SPLIT`:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{
    "priorityArea": "a273b556-f0ab-4d7a-97ac-ddb7dab06130",
    "priority": "Ensure best possible provision for pupils with specific behaviour issues",
    "startDatePicker": "10/05/2019",
    "deadlineDatePicker": "18/09/2019",
    "userPicker": "48698,48693",
    "actionWidget-1555338252504": "85e3ad8f-2586-4612-a9e7-e1c9d3f66181,6b66328f-c13f-4d8c-81ec-fccb8c1caa6e",
    "resourceWidget-1555338252504":"98714348-cf7d-4583-89d5-c7d61cafea72, 87ea276b-5b7f-4b44-b05e-775e9fd2690c",
    "sdpGrade-1555338253145": "4"
}';

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,TRIM(SS.[value])) AS resourceWidget --TRIM because your example has a leading space
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) OJ
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(OJ.[value],',') SS
WHERE OJ.[key] LIKE N'resourceWidget-%';
```